# Insertar Columna en un Dataframe dependiendo de fechas de otro Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo dos dataframes:

DF1:

```
Fecha y Hora           ID 
---------------------------------------   
12-03-2020 01:10:00    AAA   
22-04-2020 02:10:00    BBB
02-02-2020 13:55:00    CCC
15-11-2020 05:20:00    DDD
19-08-2020 14:30:00    EEE
23-04-2020 11:11:00    FFF
30-07-2020 21:40:00    GGG
11-10-2020 01:10:00    HHH
07-03-2020 01:10:00    III
06-01-2020 01:10:00    JJJ
```

DF2

```
Fecha Inicio            Fecha Fin       ID 
---------------------------------------------   
12-03-2020 01:00:00 12-03-2020 02:00:00 AAA   
22-04-2020 02:00:00 22-04-2020 02:30:00 BBB
02-02-2020 13:00:00 02-02-2020 14:00:00 JJJ
15-11-2020 05:00:00 15-11-2020 05:10:00 DDD
30-07-2020 21:50:00 30-07-2020 21:55:00 EEE
```

Lo que necesito es generar una columna en el DF1 llamada "Estatus", que diga "Si" o "No" dependiendo si la "Fecha y Hora" del df1 se encuentra entre las fecha de inicio y fecha fin del df2 y adicional a esto, debe coincidir el ID del df1 con el ID del df2, por ejemplo, el resultado seria:

```
Fecha y Hora           ID    Estatus
--------------------------------- 
12-03-2020 01:10:00   AAA     Si
22-04-2020 02:10:00   BBB     Si
02-02-2020 13:55:00   CCC     No
15-11-2020 05:20:00   DDD     No
19-08-2020 14:30:00   EEE     Si
23-04-2020 11:11:00   FFF     No
30-07-2020 21:40:00   GGG     No
11-10-2020 01:10:00   HHH     No
07-03-2020 01:10:00   III     No
06-01-2020 01:10:00   JJJ     No
```

He intentado lo siguiente pero me falta la condicion de fecha y no se como agregarla:

```
df1["status"] = df1.apply(lambda x: "si" if df2["ID"].isin(x).any() else "no",axis=1)
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Como estás utilizando `apply` en todo el `dataframe` y utilizas el argumento `axis=1` entonces tu `x` es cada fila, por lo que debes especificar la columna que deseas utilizar.

**Nota:** Cree dos `dataframe` genéricos para mostrar el funcionamiento.

En tu `apply` debes pasar las 3 condiciones:

```
((df2['Inicio'] <= x['Fecha']) & (x['Fecha'] <= df2['Fin']) & (x['ID'] == df2['ID']))
```

1. Comparar si la fecha del `dataframe` que está siendo evaluado, es decir `df1` es mayor o igual al inicio del `df2`.
2. Comparar si la fecha de `df1` es menor o igual al fin del `df2`.
3. comparar si el "ID" coincide en ambos `dataframes`.

**Nota2:** Es importante que las columnas sean de tipo `datetime64` para poder hacer la comparación.

Si únicamente aplicamos estas condiciones vas a recibir como resultado un `dataframe` donde el número de filas sea igual al número de filas de `df1` y el número de columnas sea igual al número de filas de `df2` y los valores de las celdas serían `True` o `False` indicando si se cumplen las 3 condiciones par cualquier combinación entre los dos `dataframes`.

Pero lo que nos interesa es que si cualquier (`any`) combinación es `True` entonces devuelva "si" y en caso de que ninguna combinación sea `True` entonces devuelva "no". Por lo que vamos a crear una serie con `True` o `False` dependiendo de si existe algún `True` en alguna fila de nuestra comparación.

```
((df2['Inicio'] <= x['Fecha']) & (x['Fecha'] <= df2['Fin']) & (x['ID'] == df2['ID'])).any()
```

Ahora esa serie ya puede utilizarse con tu `if`, `else` tal como lo habías puesto en tu pregunta.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

# Creamos df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Fecha': ['12-03-2020 01:10:00', '22-04-2020 02:10:00', '02-02-2020 13:55:00'],
                   'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C']})

# Nos aseguramos que la columna sea de tipo datetime64
df1['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Fecha'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

# Creamos df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Inicio': ['12-03-2020 01:00:00', '22-04-2020 02:00:00', '02-02-2020 13:00:00'],
                    'Fin': ['12-03-2020 02:00:00', '22-04-2020 02:30:00', '02-02-2020 14:00:00'],
                    'ID': ['A', 'B', 'J']})

# Nos aseguramos que las columnas sean de tipo datetime64
df2['Inicio'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Inicio'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
df2['Fin'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Fin'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

# Utilizamos apply para la comparación
df1["status"] = df1.apply(lambda x: 'si' if ((df2['Inicio'] <= x['Fecha']) & (x['Fecha'] <= df2['Fin']) & (x['ID'] == df2['ID'])).any() else 'no', axis=1)

print(df1)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
                Fecha ID status
0 2020-03-12 01:10:00  A     si
1 2020-04-22 02:10:00  B     si
2 2020-02-02 13:55:00  C     no
```